# How to implement a constantly running process in JavaEE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss7.x

How would you suggest to implement the following in JavaEE:

1. I need to have a background process in the app server (I was thinking a stateful session beans) that constantly monitors "something" and if some conditions apply it does operations with the database.
2. Most importantly it has to manipulated remotely by various clients.

So, basically, I need a process that will run constantly, keep its state and be open for method invocations by a number of remote clients.

Since I'm new to JavaEE I'm a bit confused which approach/"technology" to use. An help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a combination of a stateless session or singleton bean with an EJB timer an timer service. The bean would the interface used by the remote clients to control the background process. The timer service would periodically call back a method on the bean to verify the condition. The timers are automatically persisted by the EJB container, so they will do their job when your bean clients are disconnected.

Here is a sketch:

```
@Singleton
...
public TimerMangerbean implements TimerManager {

   @Resource
   private TimerService timerService;

   public void startMonitoring() {
      //start in 5 sec and timeout every 10 minutes
      Timer timer = timerService.createTimer(5000, 60000, "MyTimer");
   }

   public void stopMonitoring() {
      Collection<Timer> timers = timerService.getTimers();
      for(Timer timer : timers) {
         //look for your timer
         if("MyTimer".equals(timer.getInfo())) {
            timer.cancel();break;
         }
      }
   }

   //called every 10 minutes
   @Timeout
   public void onTimeout() {
      //verify the condition and do your processing
   }
}
```

See also: [Using the timer service on Oracle JavaEE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html)

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but I was hoping for a more fundamental way of doing it, the solution you suggest looks more like a trick. Is there another, more fundamental, solution that would be appropriate to a more broad range of problems of continuous processes and their manipulation.

Comment: No, is not a trick, `TimerService` and `Timer`(s) are standard way in JEE to control and execute repetitive processes. They don't tie you to a specific kind of problems. What limitations do you see in this approach? As you stated the question seems a perfect match.

Comment: +1 There is no direct support for long-running background processes in Java EE. Instead, they have support periodic timers, with the `TimerService`.

Answer (score 1):

Java EE is the solution. You will need to follow thoses steps:

1. build a Java EE application, a jar containing a EJB:

   1.1 you will need a IDE : Eclipse Juno is my favorit,
   1.2 Many tuto exists on the web. Search for EJB3 and you will find,
2. have an application server to run your EJB. JBoss is a good choice, Glassfish is an another good choice. With JBoss and the JBoss Tools plugin for Eclipse installed, you will be able to build and run rapidly an basic application.

EDIT : a complete Timer EJB class (with automatic reload if needed)

```
package clouderial.saas.commons.utils;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.ScheduleExpression;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.Timer;
import javax.ejb.TimerConfig;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import jmcnet.libcommun.exception.ExceptionTechnique;
import jmcnet.libcommun.utilit.mail.MailException;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.event.ConfigurationEvent;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.event.ConfigurationListener;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import clouderial.saas.commons.email.EmailSender;
import clouderial.saas.commons.jpamongo.JPAMongoBasePersistenceContextAccessor;

/**
 * A base class for a periodic process
 * @author jmc
 *
 */
public abstract class PeriodicProcessBase extends JPAMongoBasePersistenceContextAccessor implements ConfigurationListener {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PeriodicProcessBase.class);

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    @Inject
    protected GlobalConfiguration _config;

    @Inject
    protected EmailSender _emailSender;

    private Timer _timer=null;

    private String _processName=null;
    private Logger _log = null;

    protected void initTimer(String processName, Logger log) {
        if (processName != null) _processName = processName;
        if (log != null) _log = log;

        String second    = _config.getString("timer."+_processName+".second","0");
        String minute    = _config.getString("timer."+_processName+".minute","0");
        String hour      = _config.getString("timer."+_processName+".hours","4");
        String dayOfWeek = _config.getString("timer."+_processName+".dayOfWeek","*");

        ScheduleExpression scheduleExp =
                new ScheduleExpression().second(second).minute(minute).hour(hour).dayOfWeek(dayOfWeek);

        cancelTimer();
        if (timerService != null) { 
            _timer = timerService.createCalendarTimer(scheduleExp, new TimerConfig(_processName, false));
            _log.info("{} : timer programmed for '{}'h, '{}'m, '{}'s for days '{}'.", _processName, hour, minute, second, dayOfWeek);
        }
        else _log.error("{} : no timer programmed because timerService is not initialized. (Normal during tests)", _processName);

        // Listen to change
        _config.addModificationListener(this); // on timer modification, configurationChanged is called
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void cancelTimer() {
        if (_log != null) _log.info("Stopping timer for '{}'", _processName);
        if (_timer != null) _timer.cancel();
        _timer = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void configurationChanged(ConfigurationEvent event) {
        if (_log != null) _log.info("Configuration have change. Reloading config for ProcessBilling.");
        _config.removeModificationListener(this);
        initTimer(null, null);
    }

    @Timeout
    private void run(Timer timer) {
        runProcess(timer);
    }

    /**
     * The entry point for runner the process. Must be overriden by super class
     * @param timer
     */
    protected abstract void runProcess(Timer timer); // do the job here

}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yea, I actually run JBoss 7.1.1 and Eclipse Juno with JBoss tools. The question is which particular API to use so that the process is run constantly and, for instance, not destroyed once the client has disconnected (SLSB).

Comment: OK lets check the complete response above for implementing a TimerEJB in JBoss 7.1.1

Answer (score 1):

What about Quartz? See the links
http://rwatsh.blogspot.com/2007/03/using-quartz-scheduler-in-java-ee-web.html
http://lanbuithe.blogspot.com/2011/07/using-quartz-scheduler-in-java-ee-web.html
http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/quartz-scheduler-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

As you stated yourself, you have two requirements: 1) periodically perform some background job, and 2) respond to client requests.

For 1), you can use the `TimerService` or spawn a thread with a `ServletContextListener`. The second is not fully conform, but works. If you use timers, you can either create a periodic timer (as pointed out by @dcernahoschi), or a unique timer that reschedules itself:

```
@Timeout
public void onTimeout() {
     //do something
     // create a new timer
 }
```

If your periodic timer fires each 10 sec and you have processing that last form more than 10 seconds, you might have a problem. Having a timer that reschedules itself works better if the processing time is not fixed.

For 2) you can go with statelesss or staefull EJB, that's precisely their purpose.